# Can I use Square Brackets to pull a value from a class

Tags: c#

I have a class that has the variable "Magic". This is a 4 char string. Can I do something like this in C#?

```
string offset = chunkList["_blf"].offset;
```

*Assume that "chunkList" is an IList/List of "chunk" objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use something like this:

```
string offset = chunkList.Find(x => x.Magic == "_blf").offset;
```

Better is to check if Find retuns null:

```
Chunk chunk = chunkList.Find(x => x.Magic == "_blf");
if (chunk != null)
    offset = chunk.offset;
```

Comment: That's even better. Thank you very, very much.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can create an [indexer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6x16t2tx.aspx) on your class:

```
public string this[string s]
{
    get
    {
        // retrieve value
    }
    set
    {
        // set value
    }
}
```

Comment: But this makes it neccessary to create a descendant class of List<chunk> and add the indexer property to the descendant class....

Comment: Well, they could implement it in their `Magic` class and delegate to the chunkList.